# android USB connection charging signals

Tags: android, usb, broadcastreceiver, wireless

How can I check the USB socket is plugged or not (Charging with AC / USB)? (android version 2.1 / 2.2)

I am writing a wireless charging application that I want to get different types of charging signals ( wireless , AC charging / USB ). I used broadcastReceiver to get the charging signal and found that using wireless charging and AC charging return the same signal (AC charging). 
To distinguish wireless charging and AC charging, I want to detect the USB socket is plugged or not. I try to use Intent.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED to detect the USB signal but it also return SD card.

How can I check the USB socket is plugged or not (Charging with AC / USB)? (android version 2.1 / 2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **check device charging with AC / USB**, Lets try this,

Call `registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))`. This will return an Intent that has extras defined on `BatteryManager` to let you know if it is plugged in or not.

Something with code,

```
public class PowerUtil {
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        return plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Jellybean 4.2 there is [BatterManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS)